# Whats the best way to trigger just one rollover per link?

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

Whats the best way to trigger just one rollover per link rather than all on the page. See: http://www.4pixels.com/web-design/xweb-design.html. At the moment obviously, any and all 'li a' on the page triggers my rollover. I want to have separate rollovers on each image triggered only by itself. Hope that makes sense.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".content #display li a .caption").hide();
  $(".content #display li a").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".content #display li a .caption").slideDown(400);
  });
  $(".content #display li a").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".content #display li a .caption").slideUp(400);
  });
});
</script>

<ul id="display">
    <li><a href="/images/websites/PEX-BAFTA_2.jpg" rel="sexylightbox[group1]" title="Caption goes here"><img src="/images/websites/thumbs/PEX-BAFTA_2.jpg" alt="" /><div class ="caption">caption goes here</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please try to choose more descriptive titles for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you.

```
  $('.content #display li a').bind('mouseenter mouseleave',function() {
        $('.caption', this).slideToggle(400);
  });
```

The issue you were having is the event would fire and then you used a selector.  Use **this** to return the element that fired the event.  More or less...

Answer (score 0):

In your event handlers, try using $(this).find(".caption").

```
$(".content #display li a").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find(".caption").slideDown(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to avoid multiple event handlers.

```
$("#display").delegate('a', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).find(".caption").slideToggle(400);
});
```

N.B I may also be tempted to use something like [hover intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) so you do not show your user an unsightly animation buildup if you swipe the mouse across the screen over lots of the images.